# Unable to clear the 3d chart items after redrawing in RGraph

Tags: angular, rgraph

I am using RGraph.net to draw 3d charts in our angular 7 application.
i have to draw a 3d column chart based on user actions(like click event). when user selected 5 i can draw the chart and it has 3 items with .rgraph_accessible_text_xaxis_labels class.
after user again selected 9 so i can redraw existing chart with new data.
but first 3d chart data still exist you can check in images.
In first image only 3 items(check Browser console in image1) are there but after redraw the chart 12 items(check browser console in image2) are there but it should 9 items.

**ISSUE: I am unable to clear the previous items in 3d chart after redrawing the chart with new data**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043375/how-do-i-redraw-an-rgraph-svg-line-plot`

Comment: I am doing same but i am using canvas. But same issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

```
let canvas = (document.getElementById('cvs2'));
RGraph.reset(canvas2);
```

Comment: Should I take it from this that you resolved the issue?